# Заполнение и вывод данных из БД

Tags: cursor, запрос, android, java, база-данных

Здравствуйте.
Пытаюсь заполнять бд из xml, но чтобы проверить, получается ли, пытаюсь так же вывести таблицу в логкат.
Но у меня ошибка в строке

```
Cursor cursor = sqdb.query(DB.TABLE_NAME, new String[]
```

Лог ошибки - http://rghost.ru/56903096.view

Подскажите, в чем проблема.

БД:

```
public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private final Context fContext;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbtrans.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tntrans";
public static final String RusT = "RusT";
public static final String EngT = "EngT";
public static final String JapT = "JapT";

public DB(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    fContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + RusT + EngT + JapT
            + ");");

    // Добавляем записи в таблицу
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    // Получим файл из ресурсов
    Resources res = fContext.getResources();

    // Открываем xml-файл
    XmlResourceParser _xml = res.getXml(R.xml.dbfiles);
    try {
        // Ищем конец документа
        int eventType = _xml.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            // Ищем теги record
            if ((eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                    && (_xml.getName().equals("record"))) {
                // Тег Record найден, теперь получим его атрибуты и
                // вставляем в таблицу
                String rus = _xml.getAttributeValue(0);
                String eng = _xml.getAttributeValue(1);
                String jap = _xml.getAttributeValue(2);
                values.put(RusT, rus);
                values.put(EngT, eng);
                values.put(JapT, jap);
                db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            }
            eventType = _xml.next();
        }
    }
    // Catch errors
    catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.e("Test", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Test", e.getMessage(), e);

    } finally {
        // Close the xml file
        _xml.close();
    }

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.w("TestBase", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion
            + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

}
```

Активити:

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
DB sqh;
SQLiteDatabase sqdb;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
    // Инициализируем наш класс-обёртку
    DB dbh = new DB(this);

    // База нам нужна для записи и чтения
    SQLiteDatabase sqdb = dbh.getWritableDatabase();

    // закрываем соединения с базой данных
    sqdb.close();
    dbh.close();

}

public void eng_click (View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EngMenu.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
public void jap_click (View v){
    Cursor cursor = sqdb.query(DB.TABLE_NAME, new String[] { - В этой строчке ошибка
            DB.RusT, DB.EngT, DB.JapT }, null, // The
                                                            // columns
                                                            // for the
                                                            // WHERE
                                                            // clause
            null, // The values for the WHERE clause
            null, // don't group the rows
            null, // don't filter by row groups
            null // The sort order
            );
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        // GET COLUMN INDICES + VALUES OF THOSE COLUMNS
        String rus = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.RusT));
        String eng = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.EngT));
        String jap = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.JapT));
        Log.i("LOG_TAG", "RUS " + rus + " ENG " + eng + " JAP " + jap);
    }
    cursor.close();
    }

 }
```

Заполняю бд из этого XML:

```
<trans>
<record rus="1" eng="а" jap="A"/>
<record rus="2" eng="б" jap="B"/>
<record rus="3" eng="c" jap="C"/>
<record rus="4" eng="d" jap="D"/>
<record rus="5" eng="e" jap="E"/>
<record rus="6" eng="f" jap="F"/>
<record rus="7" eng="g" jap="J"/>
<record rus="8" eng="h" jap="H"/>
<record rus="9" eng="i" jap="I"/>
 <record rus="10" eng="j" jap="J"/>
</trans>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, бд даже не создается, а проверить я это никак не могу.

Comment: что у вас в 106 строке MainActivity.java? ошибка именно в этой строке

Comment: Cursor cursor = sqdb.query(DB.TABLE_NAME, new String[] {

Comment: а, ну конечно. sqdb == null...    
вы обьявили глобально переменную, с которой ни чего не делаете (не заполняете). в onCreate у вас вообще бред какой-то... открываете базу, и сразу закрываете

Comment: Ну а как иначе проверить, создается ли бд?
Я ее файл найти не могу через file explorer в data\data - там сплошные con-папки.

Comment: data/data/<your.application.package>/databases

Comment: и прочитайте внимательно ваш onCreate. там кроется источник всех бед. В частности, вы создаете локальную переменную sqdb, когда у вас есть глобальная с таким же именем

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно создаете таблицу:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("            + RusT + EngT + JapT            + ");");
```

Надо задавать список полей с разделителем и указанием хотя бы типа. А то получается вы создаете таблицу с одним полем `RusTEngTJapT`

Comment: Изменил на это.

      db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
    + RusT + " text not null, "
    + EngT + " text not null, "
    + JapT + " text not null, "
    + ");");


Вообще, я делаю по примеру http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite/filltable.php и у автора по первому варианту создается таблица с несколькими полями.
По поводу ошибки можете что-нибудь подсказать?